# Show that the constant polynomial $g $ closest to $f$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

In the vector space $C(1,3)$, endowed with the internal product $$\langle f, g \rangle = \int_ {1}^{3} f (x) g (x) dx $$ for all $f, g \in C (1,3) $. For $f (x) = \dfrac{1}{x} $ with $x \in (1,3) $, show that the constant polynomial $g $ closest to $f $ is $g (x) = \dfrac{\ln (3)}{2} $. Calculate $|| f-g || ^ {2} $

What do you mean with a closer function?

Comment: This is an approximation problem. We show that the polynomial that minimizes the error in approximation is the given $g$.

Comment: And how can I solve it? because I found some exercises right here on the platform, but I do not understand them very well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have
$$
||f-g||^2 = \int_1^3 (f-g)^2(x)dx = \int_1^3 (1/x-g)^2dx = 2 g^2 - g \log(9) + 2/3 =p(g)
$$
The parabola $p(g)$ has a minimum at $g^*=\log(3)/2$ and $||f-g||^2$ is precisely $$p(g^*)=\frac{4 - 3 \log^2 3}{6}$$

Comment: Excellent! thank you very much ...  apologize, you have a material where you can do the justifications of the procedure, that is, a little theory about the subject.

Comment: Not sorry. You ask for the constant $g$ "closest" to $f$. This is by definition the constant $g$ that minimize (as a function of $g$) $||f-g||$ and, since $||f-g||\geq 0$ and $h(x)=x^2$ is an increasing function in $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$, this is equivalente to minimize $||f-g||^2 = \langle f-g,f-g\rangle$.

Comment: For instance, if you ask by the linear function $g$ closest to $f$, now you substitute $g=ax+b$ before the integration and minimize using 2-variables optimization $a$ and $b$.